# What is the term for an exam which is conducted physically in an examination hall with all the students on the premises?

Tags: single-word-requests, phrase-requests

Due to the Covid 19 situation most of the universities conducted online exams. The exams were held online using internet tools via a computer. When it comes to compare the online exam with an actual examination, what is the best term to use for an actual exam which is conducted physically in an examination hall with all the students on the premises in a given time period? I find it rather odd to use *physical examination* because it sounds like it’s a medical examination. *Offline examination* is another term which came into my mind but still I feel like it is not the correct term. Could anyone kindly tell me the correct phrase to be used which is matching with the context?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

***In-person** exam* is the wording that comes to my mind. For example:

- > [States should postpone in-person bar exams during COVID-19 pandemic, ABA House says](https://www.abajournal.com/news/article/states-should-postpone-in-person-bar-exams-during-the-covid-19-pandemic-says-aba)
- > [NJ In-Person Boating Exam](https://www.register-ed.com/programs/newjersey/4-nj-in-person-boating-exam)
- > All exams are computer based and will be completed in person at one of our test sites around Washington State. — [Assessments for Grades 3–8 | Washington Virtual Academies](https://wava.k12.com/how-it-works/assessments/grades-3-8-assessments.html)

You can also use it as an adverb:

- > The Board of Regents and Department's task was to create a framework to help guide schools and school districts as they continue to plan for school to return in the fall, whether instruction takes place in person, remotely, or through some combination of the two. — [Reopening Schools Guidance - New York State Education](http://www.nysed.gov/common/nysed/files/programs/reopening-schools/nys-p12-school-reopening-guidance.pdf)

Comment: The word *remotely* in the last quotation should be noted, as it is probably a better term than *online* for the exams and instruction that are not in person.  There can be exams that in which the candidates sit together in a classroom and use networked computers that are installed there; such exams would be online, but still in person.

Answer (score 1):

Conducting a Google search for ["examinations, whether online or"](https://www.google.co.uk/search?source=hp&ei=PqBcX7eNC46Wa4DDg-AH&q=%22examinations%2C+whether+online+or%22&oq=%22examinations%2C+whether+online+or%22&gs_lcp=CgZwc3ktYWIQAzIICCEQFhAdEB4yCAghEBYQHRAeMggIIRAWEB0QHjoFCAAQsQM6CAgAELEDEIMBOgIIADoKCAAQsQMQRhD5AToGCAAQFhAeOggIABAWEAoQHjoFCCEQoAE6BwghEAoQoAFQvgxYlGNgg2ZoAHAAeACAAWiIAYISkgEEMzEuMpgBAKABAaoBB2d3cy13aXo&sclient=psy-ab&ved=0ahUKEwi3pPPgsePrAhUOyxoKHYDhAHwQ4dUDCAk&uact=5) gives (among others) the following results:

- *examinations[,] whether online or offline* (often sources in India)
- *examinations[,] whether online or face-to-face* (not really appropriate for written exams)
- *examinations[,] whether online or on paper* (though even exams conducted in central venues may be non-paper)
- *examinations[,] whether online or on-site* (DU’s Sociology department)

I'd go with **on-site**, though *offline* is catching on.

Comment: The OP is right to be skeptical about the appropriateness of *offline*, because that term can be taken to include various take-home exams written on paper, without the use of computers, in addition to the exams written in a classroom. The same is true of *on paper*, which also, obviously, cannot be used for oral exams.