# What is the proper term for a "physical event"?

Tags: single-word-requests, phrase-requests

I want to express the idea that an event, which has been conducted as a virtual event for a while is now resuming back to a normal event where people actually meet.
In other words, I want to emphasis that the event is not virtual/online.

The sentence I want to frame is something like -

> *Company XYZ is resuming ABC Meet (non-virtually)*

Words I have considered onsite and physical. Neither sounded right to me.
What is the best way to express this idea?

Comment: While about a slightly different type of event, I think this is answered well by [What is the term for an exam which is conducted physically in an examination hall with all the students on the premises?](https://english.stackexchange.com/q/546448/191178)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The expression is ***[in person](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/it/dizionario/inglese/in-person)***:

> by meeting with someone rather than talking on the phone, e-mailing, or writing to the person.
>
> - *You must apply for the license in person.*

***in-person***
(adjective)

> involving someone's physical presence rather than communication by phone, email, etc.:
>
> - *an in-person interview/meeting/visit*

(Cambridge Dictionary)

Comment: Also *face-to-face*.